# 27m" in zsh, why does it appear?

Tags: git, shell, zsh

Running command manually:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an%Cgreen%d %Creset%s" --date=short
```

**Using Bash**

```
6bb9849 2012-08-05 My Name (HEAD, master) blah2
42b3a11 2012-08-05 My Name blah1
```

**Using ZSH**

```
27m" 6bb9849 2012-08-05 My Name (HEAD, master) blah2
42b3a11 2012-08-05 My Name blah1
```

Where did **27m"** come from using ZSH please?

Few tests confirm that only top most commit shows **27m"**

Comment: `%` is a special character in zsh. You may need to use `%%` where you currently have `%`.

Comment: That `27m"` looks suspiciously like the `\e[27m` that is used to turn off invert fg/bg color. No idea why that's show up only for ZSH though.

Comment: @Amber Thanks! Please answer the question and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is a special character in zsh. You may need to use `%%` where you currently have `%`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle the same thing would be to precede `%s` with `""` to make it `%""s`